# Installation error Xampp 1.8.1 in windows 8

Tags: xampp

Hi I'm trying to install XAMPP 1.8.1 in windows 8. But seems that I cant get MySql to work!
The green color tick is visible however and but 'module' is not colored in green. Please help. Few information is listed below which I presume will help you in recommending me a solution. Thank you.

MySql error log shows as follows;

```
121123  9:07:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  9:07:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  9:07:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  9:07:39 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  9:07:39 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  9:07:39 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  9:07:39 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  9:07:39 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  9:08:06 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  9:08:06 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  9:08:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  9:08:08 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  9:08:08 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  9:08:08 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  9:08:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  9:08:08 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  9:10:31 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  9:10:34 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  9:10:34 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  9:10:34 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  9:10:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  9:10:35 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  9:10:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  9:10:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  9:10:42 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  9:10:42 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  9:10:42 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  9:10:42 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  9:10:42 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  7:41:42 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  7:41:42 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  7:41:42  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  7:41:43 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  7:41:43 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  7:41:43 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  7:41:43 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  7:41:43 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  7:46:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  7:46:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  7:46:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  7:46:13 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  7:46:13 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  7:46:13 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  7:46:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  7:46:13 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  7:47:40 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  7:47:40 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  7:47:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  7:47:42 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  7:47:42 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  7:47:42 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  7:47:42 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  7:47:42 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:53:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:53:58 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:53:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:54:00 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:54:00 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  8:54:00 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:54:00 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:54:00 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:55:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:55:36 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:55:36  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:55:37 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:55:37 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  8:55:37 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:55:37 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:55:37 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:55:48 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:55:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:55:48  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:55:49 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:55:49 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  8:55:49 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:55:49 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:55:49 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:55:55 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:55:55 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:55:55  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:55:56 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:55:56 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  8:55:56 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:55:56 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:55:56 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:56:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:56:45 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:56:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:56:47 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:56:47 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121123  8:56:47 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:56:47 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:56:47 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:58:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:58:05 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:58:05  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:58:06 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:58:06 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
121123  8:58:06 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:58:06 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:58:06 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:58:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:58:13 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:58:13  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:58:14 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:58:14 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
121123  8:58:14 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:58:14 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:58:14 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:58:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:58:29 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:58:29  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:58:30 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:58:30 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
121123  8:58:30 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:58:30 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:58:30 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:58:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:58:44 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:58:44  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:58:45 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:58:45 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
121123  8:58:45 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:58:45 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:58:45 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
121123  8:59:12 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121123  8:59:12 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121123  8:59:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121123  8:59:13 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121123  8:59:13 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3307
121123  8:59:13 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121123  8:59:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121123  8:59:13 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: 'host' (errno: 2)
```

and inside Xampp control panel i see the following;

```
08:58:40  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
08:58:40  [main]    Windows Version:   64-bit
08:58:40  [main]    XAMPP Version: 1.8.1
08:58:40  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.1.0 3.1.0 [ Compiled: September 20th 2012 ]
08:58:40  [main]    Running with Administrator rights - good!
08:58:40  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "d:\xampp\"
08:58:40  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
08:58:40  [main]    All prerequisites found
08:58:40  [main]    Initializing Modules
08:58:40  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 80
08:58:40  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 443
08:58:40  [filezilla]   XAMPP FileZilla FTP Server Service is already running on port 21
08:58:40  [filezilla]   XAMPP FileZilla FTP Server Service is already running on port 14147
08:58:40  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
08:58:40  [main]    Control Panel Ready
08:58:44  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
08:59:12  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Answer (score 0):

Under *C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql* directory you should see a *host.MYD* file and it should have a zero size.

If this file is missing then you may create one..

If this doesn't work then you may download and install xampp afresh..Use [this link](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.8.1-VC9.zip) for downloading..